# Easy management of multiple connections

Tags: windows, internet, local-area-network, connection, modem

on a Windows 7 machine I need to switch back and forth two connections: the LAN connection (that works behind a proxy) and a wireless connection via a USB modem. This requires every time to activate / deactivate two connections in the manager and switch on / off the LAN settings.

I don't think there is some way to keep two connections alive and specify which one to use based on the program, but my question is: is there a simple little utility that makes switching the connection one-click easy and fast?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check the command line utility "netsh"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732279%28WS.10%29.aspx